# Java automatic type promotions

Tags: java

I quote from Herbert Schildt : JAVA, The Complete Reference 8th Edition.

Chapter 4 : Operators

Java’s automatic type promotions produce unexpected results when you are shifting `byte` and `short` values. As you know, `byte` and `short` values are promoted to `int` when an expression is evaluated. Furthermore, the result of such an expression is also an `int`. This means that the outcome of a `left shift` on a `byte` or `short` value will be an `int`, and the `bits` shifted `left` will not be lost until they shift past `bit` position `31`.

Furthermore, a negative `byte` or `short` value will be **sign-extended** when it is promoted to `int`. Thus, the **high-order bits** will be filled with `1’s`. For these reasons, to perform a left shift on a byte or short implies that you must discard the high-order bytes of the int result. For example, if you left-shift a `byte` value, that value must first be promoted to `int` and then shifted. This means that you must discard the first `3 bytes` of the result if what you want is the result of a shifted byte value. The easiest way is to simply cast the result back into a `byte`.

```
    byte a = 64, b;
    int i;
    i = a << 2;
    b = (byte)(a<<2);
    "Binary Equivalent of b : "+Integer.toBinaryString(b); // gives 0 

    byte i1 = -5,i2;
    int s;
    s = i1<<2;
    i2 = (byte)(i1<<2);

    Integer.toBinaryString(i2); //gives 11111111111111111111111111101100   WHY?
```

I have declared `i2` to be of `byte`. Hence it should contain `8 bits`(a byte). Why `32` `bits`. Does top `3 bytes` of the result needs to be discarded. This happens to be only in case of negative numbers(here `-5`). Doesn't happens with `64`. Please suggest.

Comment: Second paragraph is the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `i2` is (in binary) `1110 1100` or (in decimal) `-20`.

The parameter-type of `Integer.toBinaryString(int)` is `int`, so `i2` gets promoted to `int`. This involves *sign extension*, meaning that the "sign bit" (the leading `1` for a negative number, or the leading `0` for a positive number or zero) gets copied to all higher bits, producing (in binary) `1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1110 1100` or (in decimal) `-20`.

It may seem strange when you look at the binary representations, but it makes sense when you look at the decimal representations. The purpose of sign extension is to preserve the actual numeric value.